# ElasticSearch - Is Parent Child relationship the best approach?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

**Problem:**

I have two types of repositories one is document and another one pages. There is a relationship between document and pages. You can think of them as one document(book) with 1 or more pages. Practically I may need to query pages from a document which matches certain criteria and vice versa. So what I am saying is I may some time query certain pages if not all from pages where the document matches.

Currently, I have created a Parent-Child relation in the Parent I have indexed the documents and in Child, I have indexed the pages with reference to the document.

But we have performance issues in our setup, the search and index queries are becoming very slow as the documents increases. I also found out that using Parent-Child relationship is not recommended as it is time-consuming for the elasticsearch [site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/tune-for-search-speed.html#_document_modeling).

Is there any other Data modelling that I could use for this problem.

Comment: For case of sql your approach is perfect but elasticsearch does not support joins like thing so manually if you are doing this it will cause performance issues. My suggestion would be not to do normalisation and keep those two in a single index by embedding docuements

Comment: @ArpitSolanki are you suggesting to use nested types?. I know that SQL is perfect for this kind of approach but the issue is page contains text data and Elasticsearch works best for Text data. So only I went on with ElasticSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Index in the page object all the informations you have in document.
If I put that in another way: do join at index time and not search time.

Comment: The issue is sometimes I want to query only the documents and not the pages. So if I embed them in index time during query I will get duplicate value. During indexing, I will be giving the same duplicate value for pages of a document.

Comment: Yes. That's ok IMO to duplicate information. If you need to search for pages, index pages. If you need also to search for documents, index documents.

Comment: But when I query for just document alone in page index I will get duplicate then I need to run the unique command which in turn is slow. i.e.) query document where pages match search criteria.

Comment: No. You create an index for pages, an index per documents. Then search in one or the other. Or both but you can boost the results from your "favorite" one.